# What are the main differences between using vector assets and normal images?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've seen that vector image assets are good for avoiding to resize images and better quality, but i've also seen that people still use image assets with 1x, 2x and 3x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the vector approach is rather new (introduced in Xcode 9) and the 1x/2x/3x is something that's been around for a while.

But I guess the simple rule for modern app development is: use vector for iconography, use classic image approach for imagery, like splash screens. (Or better yet get them from network whenever possible to reduce the bundle size)

The obvious advantages of vector for icons is small size, ability to scale images without quality loss and easier management since you only need 1 file per 1 icon.

In conclusion both approaches are handy and could be used in the same project for separate reasons. Use PDF images for small stuff like icons, use 2x/3x for raster images.

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve ever tried to resize a jpeg then you know how dangerous and useless it is to do. Because it is a lossy compression format, once you expand a JPEG too far beyond its original dimensions, the image becomes very distorted and low quality. Thus, scaling JPEGs and BMPs leaves you with a broken image that is no good to anyone. This isn’t the case with vectors. Vectors are unique in that no matter how much you scale them, you won’t see any loss in clarity, appearance, or quality. You only have to design a vector image once and you can alter the size of it as much as you need. If you create a vector logo, you can later make it large for a banner, or small for a business card. It’s as easy as that.

Also for more clarity, you can check this link:

https://www.clashgraphics.com/printing-tips/difference-between-vector-jpeg-and-bitmapgraphics/#:~:text=A%20Bitmap%20image%20or%20graphic,paths%20rather%20than%20tiny%20squares.